# How to support Airflow jinja template in sqlfluff

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, sqlfluff

I want to run sqlfluff fix command to this sql file.
This SQL is for Snowflake and will be executed in Airflow.
ti.xcom_pull is a function used in Airflow DAG.

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE date = '{{ti.xcom_pull(key='filedate')}}';
```

then I got this error in fix command.

```
L:   1 | P:   1 |  TMP | Unrecoverable failure in Jinja templating: 'ti' is
                       | undefined. Have you configured your variables?
                       | https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/latest/configuration.html
```

This means that sqlfluff does not directly support Airflow template and we have to provide variable for ti.xcom_pull. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `--ignore=templating` with `sqlfluff fix`, if you don't want to provide variables.
See https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/stable/configuration.html#interaction-with-ignore-templating